# Making a range with {} in google sheets error

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a range
={A1:A2, A3:A4}

I've got #ERROR = 'Formula parse error'

={A1:A2; A3:A4}
works fine, but makes vertical union range.

Is there any way to make horizontal union? I want to make something like
={B1:B10, A1:A10} to swap columns data.

Comment: This is an [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) as OP is just looking to do a vlookup but wants to swap the order of columns due to the limitation of vlookup.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
={B1:B4\A1:A4}
```

OR

```js
hstack(B1:B4;A1:A4)
```

Comment: Nice. hstack wins for shortest formula. However that first one doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Its for sheets with locale setting that follows [semicolon(;) convention](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/)

Comment: Thanks, '\' is what I have looked for. Somewhat ',' doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a range, you need only first and last cell for creating:

```
={A1:B10}
```

Comment: I want it in reverse order, so I want B1:B10, then A1:A10 to make VLOOKUP working, as it searches first column for values.

I can achieve that with 
=QUERY(A1:B10; "SELECT B, A", 0)

but I want to know how to do this without queries

Comment: @JamesHorsey You don't need to swap columns to do a lookup... see answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it too hard on yourself by swapping columns. Use just [xlookup](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12405947?hl=en) function instead of vlookup.

```
=XLOOKUP("first",B1:B10,A1:A10,"missing value")
```

[image]

However, in answer to your raw question, you can use [Let](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535?hl=en) and [ChooseCols](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914?hl=en) to collect the data and display it in a different order.

`=let(startRange,A1:B10,CHOOSECOLS(startRange,2,1))`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Wasn't know about this tools at all.

Comment: Great, you should `accept` either rockstart or my answer.